# Create List of strings from the string inputted by the user c#

Tags: c#, list

I have this method:

```
public List<string> AdvMultiKeySearch(string key)
{
    string[] listKeys = key.Split(',');

    string[] ORsplit;
    List<string> joinedDashKeys = new List<string>();
    List<string> joinedSearchKeys = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < listKeys.Length; i++)
    {
        ORsplit = listKeys[i].Split('|');
        joinedDashKeys.Add(string.Join(",", ORsplit));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < joinedDashKeys.Count; i++)
    {
        string[] split = joinedDashKeys[i].Split(',');
        for (int j = 0; j < split.Length; j++)
        {
            joinedSearchKeys.Add(string.Join(",", split[i]));
        }
    }

    return joinedDashKeys;
}
```

I am trying to create a method that receives a string `Keyword` that is composed of the words,comas, and '|' character. For example, user enters

> glu|sal,1368|1199

And method should produce/return List of strings: `"glu,1368", "glu,1199", "sal,1368", "sal,1199"`

It's been more than two hours and I still can't figure out how to correctly implement it. Can someone help please?

Comment: Sorry, the expected output is "glu,1368", "glu,1199", "sal,1368", "sal,1199"

Comment: My bad,  I thought that was your current output and not the expected one.

Comment: will there be more than 4 "string" as user's input?

Comment: If you mean more than 4 words in user input like glu|sal,1368|1199,info|cal then yes!

Comment: I think I can get wanted output by creating split.Length amount of items in the list and append the following indexes of the split array accordingly.

Comment: What specifically goes wrong with the code you've attempted?

Comment: @Daniel Since you want more words as stated above please provide expected outcome when there is more.

Comment: @deathismyfriend I checked the code you've provided and it does the job! I am sorry for the confusion! Thank you for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the input above this will show any number of combinations as long as there is one comma.

```
char[] splitter1 = new char[] { '|' };
char[] splitterComma = new char[] { ',' };
public List<string> AdvMultiKeySearch(string key)
{
    List<string> strings = new List<string>();

    string[] commaSplit = key.Split(splitterComma);
    string[] leftSideSplit = commaSplit[0].Split(splitter1);
    string[] rightSideSplit = commaSplit[1].Split(splitter1);

    for (int l = 0; l < leftSideSplit.Length; l++)
    {
        for (int r = 0; r < rightSideSplit.Length; r++)
        {
            strings.Add(leftSideSplit[l] + "," + rightSideSplit[r]);
        }
    }

    return strings;
}
```

Comment: @Enigmativity no it does not. That has 2 commas.

Comment: @deathismyfriend - The OP made a comment that this should handle more than one comma.

Comment: @Enigmativity I asked him and he then said no that he doesn't need it for more than one comma.

Comment: @deathismyfriend - Oh, I see. The OP is being a bit confusing.

Comment: @Enigmativity it is ok. It happens